# Any way to see which downvote was reversed?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, change-vote

Occasionally I notice I gained 2 reputation for no obvious reason. Presumably someone has just changed their mind about a previous downvote and reversed it, but they didn't leave a comment about it. Is there any way to see where this happened?

Comment: Are you also aware that when suggested edit that you made is approved, you get 2 reputation?

Comment: Of course, I suggest edits all the time. But that does show in the rep list.

Comment: I know, was just checking. :-)

Comment: It shows up on recent activity, I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation can also be "gained" if you downvoted some answer that later got deleted: you get the reputation point back. Two of these, and you get 2 reputation.

Another option is that answer of yours that had a downvote got deleted.. again the reputation is given back.

Downvote can be undone only 5 minutes after being cast, so it's unlikely that you spotted it on time.

Comment: Are you sure? I think a downvote on this answer was reversed after several hours. I had edited the answer, which I believe unlocks downvotes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238068/grep-with-regex-functionality-in-linux/7238097#7238097

Comment: @Shadow when I want to delete vote on later question/answer, I edit it by adding one character and remove my downvote

Comment: Yes editing allows vote to be undone (either up or down) - this might be the case then. No way to know, unless you remember how many downvotes you had. :)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, it is not possible.